# how to delete many objects at once using ruby aws s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I can't find how to delete multiple objects at once using the [ruby aws sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby), in the doc they have a code example on how to delete a folder that contains files :

```
# batch operations, delete objects in batches of 1k
bucket.objects(prefix: '/tmp-files/').delete
```

What am looking for is, providing files keys and delete them at once, something like this :

```
    bucket.objects(keys: [
    'avatars/0b722c42-4003-42cc-887c-b820cad3aed9/avatar1.png',
'avatars/be1275f1-664f-4d47-9890-b5b2a066a18f/avatar2.jpg', 
    'avatars/f5051ed2-b2e7-4844-bdc7-ca19c1900ce8/avatar3.gif'
    ]).delete
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [delete_objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Bucket.html#delete_objects-instance_method)
As the documentation example:

```
bucket.delete_objects({
  delete: { # required
    objects: [ # required
      {
        key: "ObjectKey", # required
        version_id: "ObjectVersionId",
      },
    ],
    quiet: false,
  },
  mfa: "MFA",
  request_payer: "requester", # accepts requester
})
```

so in your example:

```
bucket.delete_objects({
 delete:{
  objects: [
   {key: 'avatars/0b722c42-4003-42cc-887c-b820cad3aed9/avatar1.png'},
   {key:'avatars/be1275f1-664f-4d47-9890-b5b2a066a18f/avatar2.jpg'}, 
   {key:'avatars/f5051ed2-b2e7-4844-bdc7-ca19c1900ce8/avatar3.gif}'
  ]
 }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me a lot of headache :)

Comment: @Paulo Fidalgo do you know if there is any way to bulk retrieve objects using their keys (in a similar fashion)?